# TFS build failing when adding a .runsettings file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, tfs

I'm trying to specify a runsettings file from VS to add some coverage rules.

Since I added it, one of the tests started to fail.

The test uses reflection to load a dependent assembly and enforce some validation on its classes.

```
String FluentMigratorFullName = "MyAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null";
var fluentMigratorAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(FluentMigratorFullName);
var fluentMigratorAssembly = Assembly.Load(fluentMigratorAssemblyName);
```

The error I get is:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This works fine locally.

I know there is a AssemblyResolution parameter, but the location would be different at each execution as it depends on the agent picking up the build.

This is my .runsettings

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>

  </RunConfiguration>

  <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*MyModule.*</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>

            <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>

    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>

  <!-- Parameters used by tests at runtime -->
  <TestRunParameters>

  </TestRunParameters>

  <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->

  <!-- MSTest adapter -->
  <MSTest>
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>false</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
    <CaptureTraceOutput>true</CaptureTraceOutput>
  </MSTest>

</RunSettings>
```

UPDATE:

I noticed that the "Run tests in parallel on multi-core machines" was active before.

Turning it back on fixed the issue. Any idea why? [image]

Comment: If runInParallel set, tests will run in parallel leveraging available cores of the machine. This will override the MaxCpuCount if specified in your runsettings file. `I know there is a AssemblyResolution parameter, but the location would be different at each execution as it depends on the agent picking up the build.` Could there be some conflicts when running tests in multiple agent which caused the error in your question.

Comment: In the end we ended up running the problematic test on a separate test. To be honest, the information provided by the logs was not very good, and having to create a separate agent queue where to enable fusion log seemed a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we ended up running the problematic test on a separate test step. To be honest, the information provided by the logs was not very good, and having to create a separate agent queue where to enable fusion log seemed a bit an overkill.